# How do I host a React app in Google Storage Bucket behind Cloudflare?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-cloud-storage, cloudflare

I have a small static website in React that I want to deploy to Google Storage Bucket.

I have a **router.jsx** similar to this

```
<Route component={App}>            
  <Route path="/" component={AuthenticationFirewall(AccessSecurity(MainPanel), Login)}>
     <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
     <Route path="/companies" component={Companies}>
       <IndexRoute component={CompaniesTable} />  
       <Route path="/companies/:id" component={CompaniesDetail} />
     </Route> 
  </Route> 
</Route>
```

When I access the index page and I click through everything to, say, */companies/12*, everything seems ok.

However, when I access the *domain.com/companies/12* directly from a link (no previous clicking to get there), I get a **404 error**.

The Bucket's webserver doesn't allow me to set something I'd set in **nginx**

```
 location / {
    root /var/www/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
   }
```

to handle the routes correctly.

I also want to have **Cloudflare's** http proxy because of the **https** and I feel like there might be something wrong with them serving **their custom 404 error pages**.

Questions:

- How do I set the Bucket's webserver to serve the js app routes correctly?
- Do I need to set something on Cloudflare's webserver part?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The main trick is**:

The Google Storage Bucket's webserver needs to serve **index.html in case of 404 errors**

[image: Set the webserver]

**Cloudflare**:

You need to disable a feature called **Smart Errors** in Page Rules

[image: Disable Smart Errors]
so that the Cloudflare's webserver let's the Bucket to handle the errors "correctly"

More here:
https://www.ackee.cz/blog/en/how-to-host-static-react-apps-in-google-storage-bucket-behind-cloudflare-cdn/

Comment: I couldn't find the "Smart Errors" rule in cloudflare but the google storage 404 page trick fixed it for me.